# Scala: flattening a map into a map

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have the following 2 lists:

```
val a = List(List(1,2,3),List(2,3,4),List(3,4,5))
val b = List(1,2,3)
```

I want to filter elements in `a` that contain an element in `b` and add them to a Map like so:

```
Map(1 -> List(List(1, 2, 3)), 2 -> List(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4)), 3 -> List(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4), List(3, 4, 5)))
```

I tried the following:

```
b.map(x => Map( x -> a.filter(y => y contains x)))
```

but it gives me

```
List(Map(1 -> List(List(1, 2, 3))), Map(2 -> List(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4))), Map(3 -> List(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4), List(3, 4, 5))))
```

How do I flatten this into a single Map? Is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the answer:

```
Map(b.map(i => (i, a.filter(_.contains(i)))):_*)
```

As you can see, you were pretty close, but you were calling `Map()` (that is, `Map.apply()`) too 'early'. Rather, you should create a List of tuples first, since you can pass a sequence of tuples to `Map.apply()`.

**Update:** As aztek says, this can be simplified:

```
b.map(i => (i, a.filter(_.contains(i)))).toMap
```

Comment: No need for `Map.apply()` here, there's a `.toMap` method, that converts a list of 2-tuples to a map.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if parens make your eyes boggle,

```
scala> for (k <- b; c <- a; if c contains k) yield k -> c
res4: List[(Int, List[Int])] = List((1,List(1, 2, 3)), (2,List(1, 2, 3)), (2,List(2, 3, 4)), (3,List(1, 2, 3)), (3,List(2, 3, 4)), (3,List(3, 4, 5)))

scala> .groupBy(_._1)
res5: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[(Int, List[Int])]] = Map(2 -> List((2,List(1, 2, 3)), (2,List(2, 3, 4))), 1 -> List((1,List(1, 2, 3))), 3 -> List((3,List(1, 2, 3)), (3,List(2, 3, 4)), (3,List(3, 4, 5))))

scala> .mapValues(_.map(_._2))
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[List[Int]]] = Map(2 -> List(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4)), 1 -> List(List(1, 2, 3)), 3 -> List(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4), List(3, 4, 5)))
```

Someone said recently that he often has to do this operation, namely flattening the values; now I wonder if this is what he meant.